# How can I select a.m or p.m time in Timepicker?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm getting difference between two dates excluding weekend.But I want to get the time A.M at the end of the day.Because If staff start to work at the p.m then I want to add permission day half time.How can I do it?

```
private void Calculation() {
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    Date d3 = null;
    Date d4 = null;

    try {
        d3 = sdf.parse(izinSaatim); //String izinSaatim value parse to date
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        d4 = sdf.parse(basSaatim);String basSaatim value parse to date
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Calendar c3 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c3.setTime(d3);
    Calendar c4 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c3.setTime(d4);
    if(d3.getTime()>=Calendar.AM || d4.getTime()>=Calendar.AM){
      //....
    }
}
```

> Difference between two date:

```
  private void hesapla() {

        final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;
        try {
            d1 = format.parse(izinTarihim);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            d2 = format.parse(basTarihim);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(d1);
        int w1 = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -w1);

        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.setTime(d2);
        int w2 = c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        c2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -w2);

        long days = (c2.getTimeInMillis() - c1.getTimeInMillis()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        long daysWithoutWeekendDays = days - (days * 2 / 7);
        if (w1 == Calendar.SUNDAY && w2 != Calendar.SATURDAY) {
            w1 = Calendar.MONDAY;
        } else if (w1 == Calendar.SATURDAY && w2 != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            w1 = Calendar.FRIDAY;
        }

        if (w2 == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            w2 = Calendar.MONDAY;
        } else if (w2 == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
            w2 = Calendar.FRIDAY;
        }
        long a = daysWithoutWeekendDays - w1 + w2;

        gunSayi = Long.toString(a);

        kullanilan.setText(gunSayi);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.S aa");
 String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(new Date()).toString();
 System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

you will get **11-Aug-05 12.25.15.375 PM**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get AM or PM from Calander object do below code

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int a = now.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
if(a == Calendar.AM)
     //the time is PM . do necessary actions
else
     // time is PM . Do neccessary actions
```

Comment: What can I do my simpledateformat?  final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");

Comment: What actually you want ?

If you want the time difference, why you go for simpledate formatter ? just take the timeInMillies and apply to calnder object take the get the hors or days or weeks . It is very simple

or anything else please specify your need?