# Converting date and time strings to date in specific format

Tags: java, android, date, datetime-format

I am working on an Android app.

I get a date String and a time string from a `JSON` file.

```
fecha_reporte = "2017-12-17" 

hora_reporte = "23:51:00"
```

I need to convert both strings into a date variable, then later I will need to make some calculations with it.

This is what I have so far:

```
String fecha = fecha_reporte + " " + hora_reporte;

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s");
String dateInString = fecha;

try {

    Date date2 = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date2);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date2));
    Log.d("DURACION","DURACION REPORTE: calculado: "+date2);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output is a date, but with this format:

```
Sun Dec 17 23:51:00 GMT-07:00 2017
```

I need it with following format: `2017-12-17 23:51:00`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, How can I Convert String to Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573250/android-how-can-i-convert-string-to-date)

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40176777/1848157

Comment: you need to change format inside SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: You can check [converting-json-date-value-into-format-day-month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767029/converting-json-date-value-into-format-day-month/47767221#47767221) .And use in your code .

Comment: You are mistaken, the `Date` doesn’t *have* the format you quote. Its `toString` method produces that format, and that cannot be changed (only in a subclass of `Date`, and you don’t want that). To format your date into a string of the desired format, you need a formatter and its `format` method. The `SimpleDateFormat` you already have should work.

Comment: Even on Android, where the notoriously troublesome and otherwise outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class is what you have built-in, it’s worth considering throwing this class away and getting [JSR-310, the modern Java date and time API also known as `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You get it for Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: Similar questions have been asked over and over before. To find a good answer fast use your search engine.

Comment: As you have no doubt noticed already, your second `System.out.println()` gives almost your needed format: `2017-12-17 23:51:0`. You probably want to use `mm` and `ss` in the format pattern string (parsing should still work). If you have any issue beyond this, you need to explain what it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you format date and time in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android)

Comment: @OleV.V., you are right. I only needed to take the value from formatter.format(date2)

Comment: In particular when you are going to do some calculations with the resulting date-time, give JSR-310 a shot, it is much better suited for date-time math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date time classes that are now legacy. Avoid them. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Parse your input strings as `LocalDateTime` as they lack information about time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Add a `T` to comply with standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String input = "2017-12-17" + "T" + "23:51:00" ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Generate a String in your desired format by calling `toString` and replace the `T` in the middle with a SPACE.

```
ldt.toString().replace( "T" , " " ) ;
```

Alternatively, generate strings in custom formats using `DateTimeFormatter` class.

For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) projects.

Comment: thank you, I will take it into account for this and future projects.